# Use laptop as display for android device?

Tags: android

I have a Samsung J5, Currently It is not useable, Because It has broken display, So I pull it out, Unfortunately Its display is so expensive, About one thirds of the total phone price...

But Every thing works fine!... So I want to use it as tools,

I thinks, it has TWRP, maybe root access also, But I an not sure,

Ok, So I need some way to program it, How can I boot it and use a laptop as display?

Comment: You cannot, laptops do not have video inputs.

Comment: via USB? with Android Debug Bridge?

Comment: You might be able to use laptop as display (https://airmore.com/display-android-screen-on-pc.html), and to remote into the Android device (https://technadvice.com/how-to-remote-android-from-pc/) and https://drfone.wondershare.com/access-phone-data/how-to-remote-access-android-phone-from-pc.html...  but how do you get the phone to install TeamViewer, Srcpy or other software without a screen?